# Get count of messages by received date

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-2003

I have the following code for counting gross number of e-mails in Outlook:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim objOutlook As Object, objnSpace As Object, objFolder As Object
    Dim EmailCount As Integer

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Set objnSpace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    On Error Resume Next

    Set objFolder = objnSpace.Folders("MyFolder").Folders("Spam")

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        MsgBox "No such folder."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    EmailCount = objFolder.Items.Count
    Set objFolder = Nothing
    Set objnSpace = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing

    MsgBox "Number of emails in the folder: " & EmailCount, , "Number of spam messages "

End Sub
```

**Could someone please give me some way to count for a particular day of the week?**

Examples:

- "NUMBER OF MESSAGES RECEIVED ON MONDAYS = 476"
- "NUMBER OF MESSAGES RECEIVED ON SUNDAYS = 121"

Or even for a particular date

- "NUMBER OF EMAILS RECEIVED ON THE 2nd November 2010"

Comment: Note that people do not like being SHOUTED at - computers gained lower-case letters 30-odd years ago, so don't do bulk upper-case output as illustrated.

Comment: how many mondays back do you want to go? Or do you mean last Monday?

Comment: @ Sasquiha: For instance all mondays. If I could get some code that essentially said: if email's sent date = ((today's date) Mod 7) = 0  "hey look this e-mail was sent to me on a monday!" and then add up all the istances of this ("you have 59 e-mails that were sent out to you on mondays") I could then fiddle around with this and say ((todays date + 1) Mod 7) = (hey look! This email was sent out to me on tuesday!" etc.

Comment: @ Jonathan: computers gained different types of formatting in order to distinguish one series of prose from another. I am sorry if my visualisation of message boxes in block capitals was either unclear or offensives to your senses. However - kudos for reformatting my code! (Stack Overflow's UI is slightly... unintuitive in this regard)

Comment: Or even just last monday! It would take more work on my part but I am getting desperate to get **some** macro working by this stage!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps add argument (Optional dteDate As Date) to whole method/function and contain the following code within the body

```
Select Case Weekday(dteDate)
  Case vbMonday  
    IsCorrectDay = True
  Case Else  
    IsCorrectDay = False
End Select

For Each MapiItem In MapiFolderInbox.Messages
  If MapiItem.TimeReceived = IsCorrectDay Then count = count + 1     
Next MapiItem
```

Comment: Alternatively if that doesn't work perhaps replace IsCorrectDay = True Case Else IsCorrectDay = False ****WITH**** dteDate = Date ..... ****and**** ..... If MapiItem.TimeReceived = Date.... **etc.**

Comment: if you prefix your code with 4 spaces, than you can indent it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you will have to look at each message and use the  TimeReceived property.

```
For Each MapiItem In MapiFolderInbox.Messages
            If MapiItem.TimeReceived = dte Then count = count + 1
        Next MapiItem
```

or something like that.

Comment: Okay - but I am unsure how to use the above code. That seems to be just cycling through all of the emails so that count will eventually jsut equal to the gross number of emails in that particular folder,and not represent e-mails sent on any particular day... ?

Comment: It cycles through all emails in folder only adding 1 to count if the date is what you want. If you want all folders, you would have another loop outside this to loop on all folders, not just the one you mentioned above.

Comment: Presumably the day I want to search for is the opposite of dte? But what would I have to do in order to have a variable that would specify this date, and also what would I need to do to create a variable which would contain an integer relating to the number of occourances of email's sent on the day I do want? :-&

Answer (score 0):

Well this is what I've got.  There does not appear to be any simple property or method to give you the answer you're wanting.  I don't know if there's any way to reference the mail items through a SQL query.  If there were, that would be the ideal approach.  Since that doesn't seem to be possible, you're only option is to iterate over ALL the items in the folder (or folders) and have several counter variables for the days of the week.   Then you increment the appropriate counter for each item.

The main problem is simply figuring out how to reference the appropriate object.

Tested in MS Outlook 2003 and appears to be working.  BUT--I haven't check to see if it's counting every item in every sub-folder of Inbox or if it's just giving a count of items in Inbox itself, but not any of the items in sub-folders of the Inbox.
Anyway, her it is:

```
Sub CountEmailsByDayOfWeek()
 'count mail items by day-of-week
 'Isaac Comer, 6-3-2011

 Dim EmCtSun, EmCtMon, EmCtTue, EmCtWed, EmCtThu, EmCtFri, EmCtSat As Long

 Dim myInbox As Variant
 Dim BUNCH_OF_Items As Items
 Dim myInboxItem As Variant

 Set myInbox = GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
 Set BUNCH_OF_Items = myInbox.Items

 ' < Handle any errors like No such folder here >

 ' clear counters for each day-of-week 
 ' "EmCt" means "Email Count". It wasn't a good choice of variable name 
 ' because some "Items" aren't "Emails", but I'm not fixing it right now
 EmCtSun = 0: EmCtMon = 0: EmCtTue = 0: EmCtWed = 0: EmCtThu = 0: EmCtFri = 0: EmCtSat = 0


' disabled test case with the "first" item in Inbox--testing to make sure I had the object reference correct
'     Set myInboxItem = BUNCH_OF_Items(1)
'          With myInboxItem
'               Debug.Print Chr(34) & .Subject & Chr(34) & " Received: "; .ReceivedTime
'               Debug.Print DatePart("w", .ReceivedTime)
'          End With

 For Each myInboxItem In BUNCH_OF_Items
      With myInboxItem
           'disabled code that shows the subject line and received time
           'Debug.Print Chr(34) & .Subject & Chr(34) & " Received: "; .ReceivedTime
           Select Case DatePart("w", .ReceivedTime) ' get the numeric day-of-week corresponding to the vb constants
                Case vbSunday
                     EmCtSun = EmCtSun + 1
                Case vbMonday
                     EmCtMon = EmCtMon + 1
                Case vbTuesday
                     EmCtTue = EmCtTue + 1
                Case vbWednesday
                     EmCtWed = EmCtWed + 1
                Case vbThursday
                     EmCtThu = EmCtThu + 1
                Case vbFriday
                     EmCtFri = EmCtFri + 1
                Case vbSaturday
                     EmCtSat = EmCtSat + 1
           End Select
      End With
 Next

 ' output
 ' send output both to a msgbox and the immediate window.
 Debug.Print "Counts for Emails received Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, and Saturday respectively."
 Debug.Print EmCtSun; EmCtMon; EmCtTue; EmCtWed; EmCtThu; EmCtFri; EmCtSat
 MsgBox _
      "Sunday:" & vbTab & vbTab & EmCtSun & vbCrLf & _
      "Monday:" & vbTab & vbTab & EmCtMon & vbCrLf & _
      "Tuesday:" & vbTab & vbTab & EmCtTue & vbCrLf & _
      "Wednesday:" & vbTab & EmCtWed & vbCrLf & _
      "Thursday:" & vbTab & EmCtThu & vbCrLf & _
      "Friday:" & vbTab & vbTab & EmCtFri & vbCrLf & _
      "Saturday:" & vbTab & EmCtSat, _
      vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Count of Items By Day-of-week Received"
End Sub
```

If this code was helpful please vote for me.  I need points.  :-)